# Unroot R-Box (Android 4.2.2 device)

Tags: root-access

I've bought an Android TV-Box from ebay - it's called `R-BOX`. I got the device with `Android 4.2.2` and root access. However I don't want root. I tried to reset the system and remove root with `SuperSU`. None of it worked. The vendor software version is `RK3066_R-BOX_ANDROID4.2.2-SDK_V1.0.0_130308`.

Comment: Did you look in the SuperSU app settings itself... For a very long time the option to completely remove itself has been there. EDIT: Why do these old questions keep popping up in my feed list?

Answer (score 0):

You could install Titanium Backup and freeze the SuperSU app which provides root access on your device. I wouldn't recommend uninstalling it if you don't know how to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

I think this device does not contain neither **su** binary nor **SuperUser**

So, At the factory level, when the software team releases the firmware build for your device, they have signed it with the public AOSP test keys, thus **ro.secure=0** and the **adbd** is probably insecure, so it will mount your device for R/W with those commands:

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Take a look at your **Build number** if it's ending with **test-keys** or **release-keys**

If you have a firmware with **test-keys** the easiest way if to find another firmware with **release-keys**